# Escape special characters in SQL INSERT INTO via C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, escaping

I have searched google and haven't found any solution for my issue yet. Basically I have a comments feed that is setup within an image gallery (similar to facebook or stackoverflow comments). Users can post comments and read comments posted by other users. This is working fine. However, if a user tries to post a comment with an apostrophe, I get a nice little web application error:

> Incorrect syntax near 's'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character
>   string ')'.

The comment that I'm posting to SQL is **81's.** I'm wanting a solution that will escape *all* special characters so that whatever the user types in, no matter what, doesn't error out.

**Code Behind**

```
Fetcher.postUserComments(connectionString, imagePath, comments.ToString(), userId);
```

**Fetcher**

```
sqlCom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Table(userId, imagePath, userComments, dateCommented) VALUES ('" + userId + "', '" + imagePath + "', '" + comments + "', '" + theDate + "')";
```

The data type is string and I've also tried doing a `.ToString()` but no luck. Thanks in advance for any helpful input.

Comment: Do not do this! You are opening yourself to [SQL Injection attacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx). Change your code so that you parameterize all of your queries. You will be sorry otherwise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should always use parameterized querys. They help you avoid situations like the one you are having, as well as [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
sqlCom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Table(userId, imagePath, userComments, dateCommented) VALUES (@userId, @imagePath, @userComments, @dateCommented)";

sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagePath", imagePath);
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userComments", comments);
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateCommented", theDate);
```

Comment: Thank you for the information and corrections. Everything is working good now.

Answer (score 4):

You need to duplicate the ' character in comments

```
comments = comments.Replace("'", "''");
```

Alternatively, but more safety, is to use Sql parameter, example :

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Client, Project WHERE Client.ClientName = @ClientName AND Project.ProjectName = @ProjectName";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClientName",client.SelectedValue));

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProjectName",projnametxt.Text));
```

Comment: That would be a band-aid fix. I would then have to do that for all special characters. I'm looking for a more permanent fix. Thank you for the advice though. I need to update the question to state "all special characters"

Comment: ***Like*** has special characters. Maybe escape too.

Answer (score 3):

You should NEVER do this...because it allows for easy SQL injection. I could inject malicious sql queries through a comment, something like...

```
 ;drop database master;
```

use parameters instead to avoid sql injection

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Param", value));
```