# How to Escape special characters in Microsoft SQL CE

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlcedatareader

> NB: I am using Microsoft SQL **Compact Edition 3.5**

I have a table of users.I have the display name as user input and  I need to query all the user whose display name matches the input.

```
select TOP (1) * from users where display_name like 'Abby Parker'
```

here `'Abby parker'` is the input

it is working fine in normal cases .But the problem is the display name can contain special characters

for eg display name can be `"Abby Park#er"` or simply `"%&^%&^%#%"` 
.The above query fails in such cases .I have already tried the solution specified here

[Escaping special characters in a SQL LIKE statement using sql parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703637/escaping-special-characters-in-a-sql-like-statement-using-sql-parameters)

this is how I am building the query here

```
    var command = ceConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = string.Format("select TOP (1) * from {0} where {1} like '[{2}]' ", tableName,fieldName, key);
 }
```

- {0}=>users
- {1}=>display_name
- {2}=>pattern

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you building your query? Can you please post the C# code, or is this issue just in SQL?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: It seems that the question you have linked is the solution. What doesn't work for you in those answers?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24319660/833070) instead, also prevents SQL injection attacks

Comment: Its not working in SQL CE

Comment: What is not? Could you be more specific?

Comment: select TOP (1) * from accounts where display_name like '[Abby Parker]' is not matching any rows even though there is a row with display name "Abby Paniker"

Comment: Abby Parker is not equal to Abby Paniker, like needs % inserted into the string to know there could be other things around a value, read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: sorry that was a typo its Abby Parker not Abby Paniker

Comment: Have you tried the code I posted below? Does it work if you use `=` instead of `like`? Why are you using `like` if you are passing the whole string anyway without `%`?

Comment: Yes, It works! also thanks for pointing it out I have updated like with =.As a noobie in SQL I have a lot to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24319660/833070), please try the following:

```
var command = ceConnection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = string.Format("select TOP (1) * from {0} where {1} like @key ", tableName,
                    fieldName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key);
```

Comment: This works but with a small edit @tableName and @fieldName are not resolved properly in the query.But I understood your idea and applied for `@key` only it works! Thanks